# The same results in data table

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, dplyr, data.table

I have a table with some currencies and values of positions on this currencies. And I would like to sum those values grouped by Currencies. When I do:

```
Dane2[,sum(Dane2$LPB), by = Dane2$CurrencyBase]
```

I get:

```
Dane       V1
1:  USD 29552732
2:  AUD 29552732
3:  BTC 29552732
4:  CAD 29552732
5:  CHF 29552732
6:  DSH 29552732
7:  EUR 29552732
8:  ETH 29552732
9:  GBP 29552732
10:  LTC 29552732
11:  NZD 29552732
12:  XRP 29552732
13:  PLN 29552732
```

But of course these are not the real values in the table. Where is the mistake?

Comment: I suggest reading the vignettes of `data.table` first. You probably should do `Dane2[, sum(LPB), by = 'CurrencyBase']`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using the `aggregate()` function and summing the values:

```
aggregate(Dane2$V1 ~ Dane2$Dane, FUN = sum)
```

This function is especially helpful as the columns in a data frame grow.